# invalid table while creating hash table in a procedure

Tags: sybase

why I am not able to create the # table in this procedure ?

```
drop procedure TESTMD
go
CREATE PROCEDURE TESTMD

AS
declare @SQL_TXT varchar(1000)
BEGIN

SELECT @SQL_TXT ='create table #TESTMD2 (id numeric null)'
exec (@SQL_TXT)
SELECT @SQL_TXT='select * into #TESTMD2 from TESTMD1'
exec (@SQL_TXT)
select @SQL_TXT='insert into #TESTMD2 (id) values(1)'

exec (@SQL_TXT)
END
```

i got an error `#TESTMD2 not found. Specify owner.objectname or use sp_help to check whether the object exists (sp_help may produce lots of output).`

Comment: Ok, but find out which statement is wrong (create? select? insert?)

Comment: @szpal there is nothing wrong , if run the create manually it works , if i create the table in the procedure i dont get error , however it seems its not created either

Comment: You could try creating the tables, then creating the proc, and then dropping the tables. I forget the details but I remember that in some cases, the objects referenced in the SP have to exist at creation, but can then be dropped.

Comment: @MichaelGardner bussnisse wise , they cannot do that , the creation should be in the procedure however i have posted an answer how i did fix it

Answer (score 1):

well i dont know why in exec it didnt work, however this way works

```
drop procedure TESTMD
go
CREATE PROCEDURE TESTMD

AS
BEGIN

create table #TESTMD2 (id numeric null)

select * into #TESTMD2 from TESTMD1

insert into #TESTMD2 (id) values(1)


END
```